# Как предотвратить нормальное поведение курсора при нажатии клавиш в текстовой области

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

У меня есть следующий код

```
textarea#main-text-area(
        rows="1"
        ref="textArea"
        maxlength="4096"
        v-model="message"
        :placeholder="placeholder"
        @keyup="onTextAreaKeyUp"  
        @change="onChangeMessage"
        :class="{ 'vars-error': varsError }"
        v-click-outside="onTextAreaBlur"
      )
```

И я слушаю событие keyup. Мне нужно, чтобы курсор не двигался, когда я нажимаю вверх или вниз.

Я пытался сделать следующее, но у меня это не сработало, так как курсор все равно движется

```
onTextAreaKeyUp(e) {
  if (e.key === 'ArrowDown' || e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

делайте это не на слушателе keyup, а на слушателе keydown

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).